# LaTeX: how to make a well-formed TikZ rectangle with mono-space code that is partially coloured?

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I want to make a rectangle in TikZ, which has code in it.
But, some part of the code should be coloured in e.g. blue.
My current best solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}     % for colour
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

% Define the color scheme for the code listing
\lstdefinelanguage{Scheme}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\tikzstyle{rec} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text centered, draw=black]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (input) [rec] {
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Scheme, escapechar=£]
(+ £\color{blue}{(+ 3 2)}£
   10)
\end{lstlisting}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, in the result, the text goes out of the bounds of the printed rectangle:

[image]

How can I fix this in a way such that (1) the rectangle entirely contains the blue text and (2) the blue text can be of arbitrary size?

Comment: Is the aim for this to be part of a larger tikz picture, or is the only purpose of tikz here to put the rectangle around the code? There may be other methods that typeset the code first and then put the rectangle in place afterwards.

Comment: It is supposed to be part of a larger tikz picture.

Comment: Looks like two bad things come together: a) the escapechar £ results in the early cut-off of the rect, b) lstlisting inside a nodes text gives some indent to the left. Seems to be an unwanted interaction with tikz.

Comment: @MS-SPO If I'm using `inner sep = 0pt` I'm getting a [tight box around the listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H29UC.png) I don't see any indentation. Putting arbitrary text before and after the `lstlisting` environment makes it seem as if the [blue text has been `\rlap`ed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp5gZ.png). Though, outside of a node, `lstlisting` produces its own paragraph and doesn't seem to be usable inline.

Comment: A workaround coulde be to guess a good-enough `text width`, though, the listing will always be left-aligned then.